# QuickBook Online Reconnect & expire Issue

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

After reading the document of Quick Book Online API,i have some questions

1.In order to authorize in quickbook online,i implement ConnectToQuickButton.When i click this button,i get access token & access token secret & save in database.i also get 180 days expire limit.if i don't hide ConnectToQuickButton and press again the button after 50 days,i get new access token & access token secret.Is my 180 days limit initialize newly?

2.Is the above scenerio works after 150 days i.e on 151th day? ConnectToQuickButton button works on 151th day or i have to use Reconnect API?

3.On 181th day,Reconnect will not work,does ConnectToQuickButton work? or i have go through the quickbook flow i.e Signup,Create an app?

4.I access quickbook online data by Creating instance of DataServices.If access token and access token has expired what exception(ServiceException, SecurityException etc) i catch to see that tokens have expired.

Please let me know...

sabbir

Answer (score 0):

Please refer - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app

- **Re 1**
  Yes, you get a new set of tokens and those are valid for next 180 days.
- **Re 2**
  You should call Reconnect(this is mentioned in docs too). But C2QB will work as well.
  from docs - Wait 151 days (this is now within 30 days of token expiration), call the  Reconnect API to get a new token.
- **Re 3.** On 181th day,Reconnect will not work,does ConnectToQuickButton work? or i have go through the quickbook flow i.e Signup,Create an app?

C2QB works in all scenarios. If you generate new accesstoken and accessSecret then old tokens get invalidated. New tokens will work fine.

- **Re 4.** I access quickbook online data by Creating instance of DataServices.If access token and access token has expired what exception(ServiceException, SecurityException etc) i catch to see that tokens have expired.

You'll get 401 Authentication error.

- Reconnect API ref

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api#Reconnect

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Manas,I know about the doc.Do u have any ans about 1&2.