# How to get new token after calling reconnect api of Intuit?

Tags: java, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I wrote the code to reconnect the Intuit. My code is:

```
client.reConnect(INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
"accessTOken","accessTokenKeySecret");
```

I can't be sure about it is working or not. What is the best way to test it? I went through think page of intuit:  https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/ 
but I don't have so much idea regarding to it.

**Another Main issue i am facing it that, How to get new token again??** As defined by intuit checklist, We should not call OauthFlow again.

....................................................................................................................

**Added part of question:**

I know that, Playground helping me lot.
But I am searching a mechanism to get new accessToken and accessTokenSecret after I call reconnect api. I am calling api as follows:

```
IAPlatformClient client = new IAPlatformClient();
            client.reConnect(INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
"accessTOken","accessTokenKeySecret");
```

This is working fine, because if i try to use old tokens from database it throws exception as defined by Intuit.

And This code i have to run using scheduler mechanism. After calling reconnect api, I have to update my existing keys on database But I can't get those newly generated keys. So, Please suggest me the mechanism which returns new accessToken and accessTokenSecret.

I have tried this:

```
Map<String, String> requesttokenmap=client.getRequestTokenAndSecret(INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

then,

```
final Map<String, String> oauthAccessTokenMap =
             client.getOAuthAccessToken(verifierCode, requesttokenmap.get(IntuitSSOConstants.REQUEST_TOKEN),
             requesttokenmap.get(IntuitSSOConstants.REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET),
             PropsUtil.get(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY),
             PropsUtil.get(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET));
```

But I will not have **verifierCode** code, which have to pass as a parameter in last block of code.

So, how can I get **accessToken** and **accessTokenSecret**?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this SO thread.
[QuickBook Online Reconnect & expire Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908424/quickbook-online-reconnect-expire-issue)

For your first Qts, Please check - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api

Please find below steps to get OAuth tokens using which you can make API call against your QBO account. 
If you create an app in appcenter, you'll get consumerKey and consumerSecret.
https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/IA

Using the above two tokens, you can generate accessToken and accessSecret from the OAuthPlayground. 
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA
PN - After completing C2QB(OAuth) flow, you should use 'App Menu API Test.' option which will show you accessToken and accessSecret.

All the above steps are mentioned in this - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have already created app and i have consumerkey and consumerSecret. And i am also able to call reconnect api successfully. But after calling reconnect api, how can I get those new token back on request, so that I can save those tokens again on my database.

Comment: Bydefault, accesstoken and accessSecret are valid for 6 months. Reconnect can only be used when you tokens are more 150 days old (<180 days) to renew those. If you want to generate accessToken and accessSecret for the first time, then you need to implement 'C2QB' wizard as mentioned here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/widgets. For easy of use, this wizard is implemented in OAuthPlayground tool.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented C2QB and all are working fine, only one issue is how to get updated tokens. Please see my question: I have added additional part regarding to issue while reconnection. Please, review my question again.

Comment: Following two phrases are contradictory. 'I have implemented C2QB and all are working fine" and "only one issue is how to get updated tokens". If things working fine then you should get accessToken and accessSecret in the callback. Ref impl from sample app - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/blob/master/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/java/com/intuit/controller/support/OAuthController.java. Reconnect API is not the solution of the above use case. It is only applicable when your tokens are more than 5 months old(as mentioned above and docs).

Comment: I guess you have a answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956043/qbo-integration-sync-note-field-of-vendor-customer-are-not-returning