# QBO integration: Sync Note field of Vendor/Customer are not returning

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have implemented **QBO** sync on my application and it is done. But, the one question is that

**1. Can we get Note filed of Vendor/Customer from QBO?**

I went thorough **apiexplorer** but there is not any field related to `NOTE`. Here is the response:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-11-16T02:06:42.309-08:00">

  <Vendor domain="QBO" sparse="false">

    <Id>###</Id>

    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>

    <MetaData>

      <CreateTime>2014-11-16T01:28:40-08:00</CreateTime>

      <LastUpdatedTime>2014-11-16T01:28:42-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>

    </MetaData>

    <Title>Ms</Title>

    <GivenName>Shrijana</GivenName>

    <MiddleName>K</MiddleName>

    <FamilyName>Maharjan</FamilyName>

    <CompanyName>Mrs pradhan</CompanyName>

    <DisplayName>Ms Shrijana K Maharjan</DisplayName>

    <PrintOnCheckName>Ms Shrijana K Maharjan</PrintOnCheckName>

    <Active>true</Active>

    <PrimaryPhone>

      <FreeFormNumber>(984) 915-9090</FreeFormNumber>

    </PrimaryPhone>

    <AlternatePhone>

      <FreeFormNumber>78888888</FreeFormNumber>

    </AlternatePhone>

    <Mobile>

      <FreeFormNumber>989878787</FreeFormNumber>

    </Mobile>

    <Fax>

      <FreeFormNumber>89898988</FreeFormNumber>

    </Fax>

    <PrimaryEmailAddr>

      <Address>shrijanamaharjan@lftechnology.com</Address>

    </PrimaryEmailAddr>

    <WebAddr>

      <URI>https://www.shrijana.com</URI>

    </WebAddr>

    <BillAddr>

      <Id>125</Id>

      <Line1>teku</Line1>

      <City>kathmandu</City>

      <Country>USA</Country>

      <CountrySubDivisionCode>NY</CountrySubDivisionCode>

      <PostalCode>9099</PostalCode>

    </BillAddr>

    <TermRef>2</TermRef>

    <Balance>45.00</Balance>

    <AcctNum>4555555555</AcctNum>

    <Vendor1099>false</Vendor1099>

  </Vendor>

</IntuitResponse>
```

So, Is it possible to get note of customer/vendor from **QBO**?

Thanks.

Comment: @Manas Mukherjee I guess you have a answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the 'Notes' field in 'Customer' doc and in the API response. 
But it is not supported for 'Vendor'.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/vendor

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-11-16T04:06:06.598-08:00">
  <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1">
    <Customer domain="QBO" sparse="false">
      <Id>61</Id>
      <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
      <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-10-28T15:34:22-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-11-16T04:04:52-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
      </MetaData>
      <GivenName>Alvin</GivenName>
      <FamilyName>Lee</FamilyName>
      <FullyQualifiedName>Alvin Lee</FullyQualifiedName>
      <DisplayName>Alvin Lee</DisplayName>
      <PrintOnCheckName>Alvin Lee</PrintOnCheckName>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>650-555-7777</FreeFormNumber>
      </PrimaryPhone>
      <PrimaryEmailAddr>
        <Address>alvin.lee@example.com</Address>
      </PrimaryEmailAddr>
      <DefaultTaxCodeRef>2</DefaultTaxCodeRef>
      <Taxable>true</Taxable>
      <Notes>This is a long note.</Notes>
      <Job>false</Job>
      <BillWithParent>false</BillWithParent>
      <Balance>0</Balance>
      <BalanceWithJobs>0</BalanceWithJobs>
      <PreferredDeliveryMethod>Print</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
    </Customer>
  </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Thanks